# how to sort in table of react virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

This is the [project link](https://react-ssygsm.stackblitz.io) using react virtualized table, 
i need to do sorting column-wise, but getting error while updating list array,
How to write sort() function for table to update table when user click on column Header both ASC, DESC
this is the documentation, https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/ae38b6f58478026e6f19d828cad85a05fefd4260/source/Table/Table.example.js#L31-L32

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Column, Table, SortDirection, SortIndicator } from 'react-virtualized';
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/AutoSizer';
import _ from 'underscore';
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';

import { fakeJson } from './Data/fakeJson';

const datalist  = fakeJson;
const list = datalist; 
class TableComponent2 extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(){
    super();
     this.state = {
       sortBy: 'username',
       sortDirection: SortDirection.DESC,
       sortedList: list
     }
   }
  
   sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
     console.log(list)
    const tempList = _.sortBy(list, item => item[sortBy]);
    console.log(tempList);
    const sortedList = tempList.update(
        list =>
          sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list
      );
  
    this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList });
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
          {({ width }) => (
            <Table
              headerHeight={20}
              height={740}
              rowCount={datalist.length}
              rowGetter={({ index }) => this.state.sortedList[index]}
              rowHeight={60}
              width={width}
              sort={this.sort}
              sortBy={this.state.sortBy}
              sortDirection={this.state.sortDirection}
            >
              <Column
                dataKey='id'
                width={200}
                flexGrow={1}
                label='ID'
              />
              <Column
                dataKey='name'
                width={200}
                flexGrow={1}
                label='NAME'
              />
              <Column
                dataKey='username'
                width={200}
                flexGrow={1}
                label='USERNAME'
              />
            </Table>
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default TableComponent2;
```

Comment: `const sortedList = tempList.update(
        list =>
          sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list
      );` dont't understand what is Update do? and where it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you are using an `update` method over an array and `update` is not a method of `Array`.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array.update); // undefined.
array.update(); //error.
```

What you only need to do is `reverse` your `sorteredList` based on your `SortDirection`, that is all what you need to set the state.

```
sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    console.log(list)
    const tempList = _.sortBy(list, item => item[sortBy]);
    console.log(tempList);
    const sortedList = sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list
    this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList });
}
```